# Insert array values into specific field of HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, postgresql

I need to insert values selected by pg_query and organized into array into specific fields of table with input type=text:

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="street">Street:</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Street name" required="required" id="street" name="street" onchange="sendForm(this.form)">
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="building_no">Building No:</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Number of building (XXXX)" name="bld_no">
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="ID Sector">ID Sector:</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="IotaNet Sector (5)" name="id_sector">
  </td>
</tr>
```

All values are strings and array has all selected values:

```js
$qexist = "SELECT 
       test.tb.street, 
       test.tb.bld_no, 
       test.tb.id_sector, 
  FROM test.tb
  WHERE test.tb.street = '$street'
  AND test.tb.bld_no = '$bld_no'
  "; 
  $ress = pg_query($qexist);
  while ($row = pg_fetch_array($ress)) { 

//   values of $row[] have to be inserted into exact fields
    echo $row[1].'street';
    echo $row[2].'bld_no';
    echo $row[3].'id_sector';
  ? ? ? ? ? ?
    var_dump($row);
      /* result of var_dump
array(30) { [0]=> string(20) "90315464612890004 " ["id_bld"]=> string(20) "90315464612890004 " 
        [1]=> string(50) "Street" ["street"]=> string(50) "Street" 
        [2]=> string(4) "0004" ["bld_no"]=> string(4) "0004" 
        [3]=> string(1) "5" ["id_sector"]=> string(1) "5"................ */
  }
```

Please advise how to solve this issue. I tried different ways, but unsuccessfully, despite the fact that the site displays echo and var_damp results, the fields remain empty. Thank you.

Comment: `<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row[1]; ?>" id="street" name="street" onchange="sendForm(this.form)">`. (php while has to be wrapping the html `<tr>`s). The 'onchange' is not such a good idea. It means, that if the user types the form gets sent immediately

Comment: @Jeff...this way doesn't work I tried it yesterday in different ways, especially like this:  
`<input type="text" value="<?= $row[2] ?>" placeholder="Number of building (XXXX)" name="bld_no">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Street name" required="required" id="street" name="street" value="<?php echo $row[1] ?>">

<input type="text" placeholder="Number of building (XXXX)" name="bld_no" value="<?php echo $row[2] ?>">

<input type="text" placeholder="IotaNet Sector (5)" name="id_sector" value="<?php echo $row[3]?>">
```

Comment: unfortunately change location of `value="<?php echo $row[3] ?>"` inside of `<input .... >` parameters has no effect also

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution by experimental way, but it's works. I have created new variable array `$value[]` , assign them values of `$row[]` and  code begin to work

```js
<?php>
$qexist = "SELECT 
       test.tb.id_bld, 
       test.tb.street, 
       test.tb.bld_no, 
  FROM test.tb
  WHERE test.tb.street = '$street'
  AND test.tb.bld_no = '$bld_no'
  "; 
  $ress = pg_query($qexist);
  while ($row = pg_fetch_array($ress)) { 
        $value[0] = $row[0];
        $value[1] = $row[1];
        $value[2] = $row[2];
  }
 ?>
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <form method="get" action="t54646.php">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="id_bld">Building ID:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Not for fill - system ordered" name="id_bld" value="<?php echo $value[0] ?>">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="street">Street:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Street name" required="required" id="street" name="street" onchange="sendForm(this.form)" value="<?php echo $value[1] ?>">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="building_no">Building No:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Number of building (XXXX)" name="bld_no" value="<?php echo $value[2] ?>">
        </td>
      </tr>
```

If somebody can explain why array begin works after variables renaming this will be useful for many people